# grub rescue - /grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found

Tags: linux, boot, grub

When I boot my PC (running Linux), I run into an error:

```
error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
```

and a `grub rescue>` prompt. On running `set` I get:

```
cmdpath=(hd0) 
prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/grub 
root=hd0,msdos2
```

On `ls` I get:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

On `ls /` I get nothing.

On setting `root` variable to any other value and then `ls /` gives me:

`error: unknown filesystem`

`insmod normal` gives me the same error message (normal.mod not found)

ls, set, insmod are the only commands available it seems. Have I bricked my system :/